# Why are some of the plugins inactive in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, infrastructure-as-code

I am running jenkins locally on a docker container and in my docker file, I copy a list of plugins using this command

```
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

and in plugins.txt I have multiple plugins including

```
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.13-1.0
authentication-tokens:1.4
authorize-project:latest
```

But when I go to the plugins page `http://localhost:8080/pluginManager/installed`, I see that they are inactive. What is the reason for this?
How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was a stupid question. It is inactive because `These plugins cannot be disabled as they have dependencies`. I am not deleting the question as it might be helpful to someone

Comment: Your Question is not stupid but needs clarification. The plugins themselves are not inactive; they are *Enabled*, as evidenced by the position of the switch. The control to *Enable/Disable* is *inactive* because, as you mentioned, those plugins are dependencies for other plugins and so must remain Enabled; that is evidenced by the opaque control. You can identify the dependant plugins by hovering over the control. Suggest you clarify the question, then you can self-answer, along with an image of the hover.